# MongoDB php return array of values in a cursor

Tags: php, mongodb

I got two diferent colections: *favorites* and *photos*.
They look like this:

favorites

```js
{   
    "user_id" : "1234",
    "photo_id" :"123",
}
```

photos

```js
{   
    "photo_id" : "123",
    "user_id" :"1234",
    "photo_url":"service/photos"
}
```

I want to return all photo url from a given user id.
So first i selected the photo id from the specific user
something like this:

```
  // access database
  $db = $conn->$dbname;

  // access collection
  $favorits = $db->favorits;
  $fotos=$db->photos;
  $object= 
    array(
      "id_user" => id_user
    )

  $cursor = $favorits->find($object);
```

From here i'm trying to get an array with the value
of the photo_url field.
I think i could do something with the foreach but nothing
worked so far.
Thanks guys!

Edit: Just got it. Didn´t knew i could get some specific values. Here's my solution:

```
// Config
$dbhost = 'localhost';  
$dbname = 'db_service';
$id_user = $_GET['id_user'];
// open connection to MongoDB server
$conn = new Mongo($dbhost);
// access database
$db = $conn->$dbname;
// access collection
$favorits = $db->favorits;
$photos=$db->photos;
$object= 
  array(
       "id_use"r => $id_user
  );
$cursor = $favoritos->find($object);
foreach($cursor as $document) { 
  $counter=0;
  $photoids[$counter]=$document['id_photo'];
  $photo=$photoids[$counter];
  $counter++;
  $object2= 
  array(
  "id_photo" => $photo
  );
  $photo_path=$photos->find($object2);
  foreach($photo_path as $row){
    $path_string=$row['path'];
    echo $path_string;
  }
}
```

This code echoes the path of the photo. ex: service/img/app_photos

Answer (score 0):

Since they are in 2 different collections you will have to do a loop in PHP on each favorite and get the photo URL from the photo collection.

But I think that with a minor change in your document design it will simply all the work, for example put the photo url in your favorite too.

Something like:

```
favorite
{   
    "user_id" : "1234",
    "type" : "photo",
    "resource" : {
      "photo_id" :"123",
      "photo_url":"service/photos"
    }
}
```

This will simplify a lot your application code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need both collection because there are some photos in photos that i cant find in favorits. I should have use your structure, that's for an app and i can request the photo path when i made it a favorite photo. Anyway ill edit for the solution i found. I didn´t knew how to access to a specific value. Cheers!

Comment: I am not telling you to use only one collection, I am saying that you can duplicate the information. It is something very common when you work with MongoDB/Document Databases.